# dotdotdot showing extra text after ... in flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dotdotdot

I have a flexslider carousel and it appears that for the items not yet in view dotdotdot is not applied correctly to some of them, there appears to be a text after the ...

http://dusit.syndacast.com/dusitthani/bangkok/

[image]

If I resize the window then it adjusts and works as the items are in the window view. Not sure why it happens for one but not another.

I am using the watch:true called straight after the flexslider loads.

I found one solution from another thread but not sure how to apply it to flex.

[jquery dotdotdot plugin (adds ellipsis) not working with Bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375304/jquery-dotdotdot-plugin-adds-ellipsis-not-working-with-bootstrap-carousel)

Thank you!

Comment: This does not appear to be happening on my browser google chrome, what browser are you viewing the page on? You could always add this to the element : `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: Using chrome too on windows. Your solution seems to work well but there's a <br> in the content which puts a ... after that and after the end of the content because of 'white-space: nowrap;'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>hello world this is a long text</div>
<style>
div{
    width:50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't set a width, this solution only works for one line unfortunately, multi lines it doesn't show the ... at the end, I would have loved to use this solution otherwise.